# Can it be the reason to destroy the odoo system?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to ask the experts, can this code be the reason to destroy/corrupt the odoo system ?

Screenshot :   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1z0uFL2bSV4Z4ZI-CEDlCX2EXic0BeCMe

And Is the following video is about to insert upper code in odoo ?

Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGEUtvWPd68

I need your suggest guys. Thanks?

Comment: **In apps** (`modules`) is just a computed char field that is read-only, unless you define the [reverse](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#basic-fields) function.

Answer (score 0):

First: No visible reason to destroy the system.
Second: The video is about using selenium scripts to automate inserting data in `product.template` model, not related to `res.users` model showed in upper screenshot.

Comment: actually one of our odoo developer was saying that because these codes are there so system crashed, and in the video, someone demonstrated how to do that.

Comment: You have to share the codes without that it is not clear what you are implying.

Comment: Those are not code. Anyway, the UI screenshot you provided has nothing destructive in it.